# Common practice for abandonware in SVN

Tags: svn

I have a general repository for small utilities (which were deemed too small at the time to warrant their own repository. 'Nother problem of itself maybe), some of which are deprecated and likely to never serve again. But one rule where I work is to never throw anything away. Deleting from SVN means it's not really deleted, it's just in the history somewhere, but that can still be hazardous in case you need to find that old thing again.

What would be the best strategy for keeping deprecated items, but also keeping them out of the way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What would be the best strategy for keeping deprecated items, but also
>   keeping them out of the way?

Move all your deprecated projects into a 'deprecated' directory.

**Edit:** I wrote previously that you could get svn to ignore files in the deprecated directory, but that turns out not to be the case. If you're used to updating all your projects at once but would like to avoid checking out deprecated projects, consider keeping all your active projects in one directory and deprecated projects in another.

Comment: What would be the client-side and server-side configurations? You don't need to explain in full, but if you have the properties, I can google them.

Comment: Doh! I thought you could use the `svn:ignore` property and `global-ignores` config option, but reading further it turns out that you can't ignore versioned files. Sorry to mislead.

Comment: Damn. It's was a solid idea too. Better inform SVN they need to work on this ASAP!

Comment: I'd guess it's a feature. For example, you could use `svn:ignore` to ignore a general pattern, but use the --no-ignore option to add a file that matches the pattern but should be controlled anyway. For example, you could ignore some settings file by ignoring the pattern `*.settings`, but still control `original.settings`. I think the better solution is just to keep active projects in one top-level folder and deprecated projects in another.

Comment: As far as I understand `svn:ignore`, it's to keep things out, like VS .suo files, local stuff, temp stuff, etc.